# Python AES decryption

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, aes

I have a Typescript code I've been trying to convert to Python (**I am interested in the decrypting part**) but I kept getting bad output, what I am doing wrong?

Code I want to translate:
Typescript

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
let encrypted = undefined;
let decrypted = undefined;
let key = "d76d312b4647849345285b7c11dbb9e6"
let data = "Data to be encrypted"

encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key);
console.log(encrypted.toString()) //results to output like this: U2FsdGVkX198Jnuf6hHeS1bDSP5mrn/+ciFwd5l4Yiw=

decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decrypted) //results to "Data to be encrypted"
```

Python

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'b9730baff3f457f7e98be4351387fcbd'

data = "Some_encrypted_base64_here"

unb64_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(data.encode())

decryption_cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)#, nonce=nonce)
output_data = decryption_cipher.decrypt(unb64_ciphertext)

print("Decrypted message: ", output_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

I tried to change the AES moode but that didn't help either

Comment: I see that you edited the key. The next thing I would try is taking a plaintext message, encrypting it in Python and then decrypting that ciphertext to see if you get the same plain text back out.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just a mistype, I tested with the correct key but I am getting the wrong output

Comment: See my suggestion in my previous comment

Comment: You have used mode AES.MODE_CBC in decryption step but It seem to be AES.MODE_SIV in encryption step, pls use same mode in whole steps

Comment: Shouldn't this line, CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key), use encrypt(data, key) not decryption since you're passing data and key?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am not even sure I am doing it right, I was just trying to translate that typescript code to Python, I tried encrypting but I got python errors

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with a "correctly" encrypted string that we can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have made changes to the Typescript code that I wanted to translate to python, hopefully this give a better understanding of what I am trying to do which is basically figuring out how to decode the salted base64 in python

Comment: The first code block doesn't use any TypeScript syntax — so I updated the tags, replacing [tag:typescript] with [tag:javascript].

Comment: Before you go any further, I think you need to be aware that when you use a passphrase in Crypto.js (which you do, even though it's a hex string), it will automatically generate a key and IV which can be accessed from `encrypted.key.toString()` and `encrypted.iv.toString()`. You'll need to use the same key and IV on the python side.

Comment: To get key and IV on the Python side, the key derivation used by CryptoJS must be done (`EVP_BytesToKey()`). The salt needed for this is contained in `encrypted.toString()` (which has the following format: Base64 encoding of: Salted__ + 8 bytes salt + ciphertext).

Comment: Then, you also have to take into account that CBC is a block cipher and that Crypto.js will apply padding to fill out the block (PKCS7 by default). You'll need to remove the padding again on the Python side.